# Django. Python social auth. create profiles at the end of pipeline

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I want to add a function at the end of the auth pipeline, the function is meant to check if there is a "Profiles" table for that user, if there isn't it will create a table. 
The Profiles model is a table where I store some extra information about the user:

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    points = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    posts_number = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Each user must have a Profiles table. So, I added a function at the end of the pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'app.utils.create_profile'  #Custom pipeline
)

#utils.py 
def create_profile(strategy, details, response, user, *args, **kwargs):
    username = kwargs['details']['username']
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if Profiles.ojects.filter(user=user_object).exists():
        pass
    else:
        new_profile = Profiles(user=user_object)
        new_profile.save()
    return kwargs
```

I get the error:

```
 KeyError at /complete/facebook/
 'details'
 ...
 utils.py in create_profile
 username = kwargs['details']['username']
```

I'm new to python social auth, and it looks that I'm missing something obvious. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From the error trace you have shown, it seems like kwargs is missing the key `details`

Comment: Well yes, that was the problem. I was following [this](http://www.masnun.com/2014/01/03/python-social-auth-custom-pipeline.html) tutorial and becouse he does `email = kwargs['details']['email']` I thought I could do `username = kwargs['details']['username']`. Anyway, I solved it by doing `username = details['username']`. But now I have a new problem... 'User matching query does not exist'. :P... anyway. thnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I'll answer my own question just in case it is useful for someone in the future. I'm no expert but here it is:

I was following [this](http://www.masnun.com/2014/01/03/python-social-auth-custom-pipeline.html) tutorial, and becouse he does

```
 email = kwargs['details']['email']
```

I thought I could do

```
username = kwargs['details']['username']
```

But it didn't work, it gave my a KeyError.

Then I tried:

```
username = details['username']
```

And it worked. But I had a new problem, the username from the details dict was something like u'Firstname Lastname' and when I tried to get the User object

```
user_object = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

It was not found, becouse the username in the User model was u'FirstnameLastname' (without the space).

Finally I read the docs again and I found out that I could simply use the user object directly, it gets passed to the function as "user":

```
def create_profile(strategy, details, response, user, *args, **kwargs):

    if Profiles.objects.filter(usuario=user).exists():
        pass
    else:
        new_profile = Profiles(user=user)
        new_profile.save()

    return kwargs
```

Comment: +1Up. One doubt, what if you want to pass some extra parameter, which is going to be used while creating the profile? The value of extra parameter will be different based on the link.? Is there a way for it?